# Why doesn't String.tap return the modified string?

Tags: ruby

I'm doing

```
String.new.tap do |string|
  polygon.points.each do |point|
    x, y = point.x + (page_padding/2), point.y + (page_padding/2)
    string += "#{x}, #{y} "
  end
end
```

But it returns an empty string.

If I call

```
Array.new.tap do |array|
  polygon.points.each do |point|
    x, y = point.x + (page_padding/2), point.y + (page_padding/2)
    array << "#{x}, #{y} "
  end
end
```

It returns a modified array. Why does this not work on a string?

Using Ruby `2.4.0`

Comment: Just curious, do you have experience with another language? I've never seen any similar syntax.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I hope I didn't offend you with my comments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`+=` is not a mutator: `str1 += str2` creates a new string. Use `<<` to mutate string:

```
string1 = 'foo'
string1.object_id
=> 70298699576220
(string1 += '2').object_id # changed
=> 70298695972240
(string1 << '2').object_id # not changed: original object has been mutated
=> 70298695972240
```

`tap` just yields self to the block, and then returns self. Since `self` does not change in your instance, tap just returns the original value.

Comment: Just spell it out: `str1 += str2` creates a __new__ string. :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev, indeed

Answer (score 3):

## Solution

#### String

To get a String out of your points, just use [`map`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-map) and [`join`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-join) :

```
polygon.points.map do |point|
  [point.x + (page_padding/2), point.y + (page_padding/2)].join(', ')
end.join(' ')
```

#### Array

To get an aray, just use [`map`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-map) :

```
polygon.points.map do |point|
  [point.x + (page_padding/2), point.y + (page_padding/2)]
end
```

## + and <<

`+` and `<<` can both be used on Array and Strings, with a very similar behaviour for both classes. `+` creates a new Array or String, `<<` mutates the original one.

```
s = "1 2"
#=> "1 2"
s + " 3"
#=> "1 2 3"
s
#=> "1 2"
s << " 3"
#=> "1 2 3"
s
#=> "1 2 3"
a = [1, 2]
#=> [1, 2]
a + [3]
#=> [1, 2, 3]
a
#=> [1, 2]
a << 3
#=> [1, 2, 3]
a
#=> [1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: I think leaving the standard pry prompt is quite distracting. Perhaps use the `--simple-prompt` pry flag.

Comment: True. Pry has been removed